# In Emacs, how can I check all open files for changes?

Tags: emacs, tramp

Working with >1 Emacs (on >1 machine), and want to check all open buffers for changes (they are open remotely via tramp/ssh) when I resume working on a particular Emacs.

Different Emacs might not have the exact same files open, but there is probably crossover.

Not using Desktop mode or anything flash like that (yet).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm aware that I'll be prompted when I save any buffer if it's been changed remotely, but then I need to work out the correct solution. As I will have saved and walked away, the ideal solution for me is to re-open all open files.

Comment: I suspect your use case is unique enough that there isn't a default solution.  You may want to look into the means by which the unsaved buffers are identified when list-buffers is run.  From there you might be able to create a shared resource/file that could be viewed from any session/instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting buffers to revert in Emacs when the associated files are changed by another program, then you should look at
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `global-auto-revert-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to revert any buffers to their file's contents if the file has been modified outside emacs.

Here's a little snippet of lisp that will loop through the unmodified buffers and reloads the contents from disk:

```
(require 'cl)
(loop for buffer being the buffers
      do (when
             (and (not (buffer-modified-p buffer)) (buffer-file-name buffer))
           (switch-to-buffer buffer)
           (revert-buffer nil t)))
```